# Highlight error on specific textbox: KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Using asp.net mvc, c#, knockoutjs

I have a textarea and a ADD button next to it. User can enter in the textarea and press CHECK button or they can click the ADD button to add another textarea and then click CHECK button. There is no restriction to no of textarea they can add.
When they press the CHECK button I the code hits my MVC controller method and does some validations on the input. If the input is fine I proceed else show error.

My issue is highlighting and displaying the correct error. Right now I am just using one generic error label to show error. I want to show error to the textarea which has the error not a generic one. I have my code as below.

```
<form id="form" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="FilterMaintenance" method="post">
<div class="form-horizontal" style="margin-top:50px">
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: records }">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <textarea rows="1" class="required text-danger form-control textbox-wide" data-bind="value: $data.input, attr: { name: 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input', id: 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input'}"></textarea>
            <span class="help-block-msg field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-bind="attr: { 'data-valmsg-for': 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input'}"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">                       
            <input type="button" value="Add Record" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.addRecord, visible: function(){ return !($index() != $parent.records().length - 1) }()" />
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="button" value="Check Input" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind='click: checkInput' />
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="form-group" data-bind="visible: errorFlag">
        <span data-bind="text: errorText"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Knockout code:

```
(function () {
var viewModel = function (vmData) {

    var self = this;        
    self.errorFlag = ko.observable(false);
    self.errorText = ko.observable();        
    self.records = ko.observableArray();

    self.records([{            
        input: ""
    }]);

    self.addRecord = function () {           
        self.records.push(
            {
                input: ""
            });
    };

    self.checkInput = function () {

        var returnVal = false;
        var records = self.records();
        var input = JSON.stringify(records);
        //With abc as first and def as second texarea entry I get as below
        //"[{"input":"abc"},{"input":"def"}]"

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",                
            async: false,
            url:"/Home/CheckRecord",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
            data: {                
                "input": input
            },
            success: function (data) {
                self.errorFlag(true);
                if (data == '') {
                    self.errorText('Input is correct');                                                
                    returnVal = true;
                }
                else {
                    self.errorText('Input is not correct: ' + data);                                                
                    returnVal = false;
                }
            }
        });

        return returnVal;
    }
}      

    var pageVM = new viewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(pageVM, $("form")[0]);

})();
```

MVC Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CheckRecord(string input)
    {
       string parseError = string.Empty;
       bool inputCheck = false;
       string returnValue = string.Empty;

        inputCheck  = false;//doing some checks here then return true or false
        returnValue = inputCheck ? "" : "error";

        var ret = Json(returnValue);

        return ret;
    }
```

Also I get the below generated HTML for 2 textarea added:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <textarea rows="1" class="required text-danger form-control textbox-wide" data-bind="value: $data.input, attr: { name: 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input', id: 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input'}" name="Records[0].Input" id="Records[0].Input"></textarea>
                    <span class="help-block-msg field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-bind="attr: { 'data-valmsg-for': 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input'}" data-valmsg-for="Records[0].Input"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">                       
                    <input type="button" value="Add Record" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.addRecord, visible: function(){ return !($index() != $parent.records().length - 1) }()" style="display: none;">
                </div>              

            </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 ">
                    <textarea rows="1" class="required text-danger form-control textbox-wide" data-bind="value: $data.input, attr: { name: 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input', id: 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input'}" name="Records[1].Input" id="Records[1].Input"></textarea>
                    <span class="help-block-msg field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-bind="attr: { 'data-valmsg-for': 'Records[' + $index() + '].Input'}" data-valmsg-for="Records[1].Input"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">                       
                    <input type="button" value="Add Record" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $parent.addRecord, visible: function(){ return !($index() != $parent.records().length - 1) }()">
                </div>              

            </div>
```

Sorry for the long post but wanted to show the full code for explanation.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Update:

I have a added this in jsfiddle as well:

```
 https://jsfiddle.net/gmmmh873/
```

Comment: Anyone for inputs?

Comment: Why are you setting error text in success message?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [Knockout-Validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation). It can handle most of this for you, and has great [documentation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki) to get you started. This injects error messages per input field when the rules are not met. You can also trigger these from the response back from your xhr call as well.